# Azure Create a Mobile Service always prompts "the name is already in use"

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

While creating a azure mobile service, I need to enter the URL of my database which is supposed to end with `".azure-mobile.net"`, no matter what name I give, it always says that `"the name is already in use"`. Please help.

Comment: Can you give some examples of names you have tried? And just to ensure you're not entering `.azure-mobile.net` in the textbox for mobile service name. Correct?

Comment: No i am not entering    .azure-mobile.net    in the end, i have tried several combinations including name of my 3 friends coupled with my name and also random characters.

Comment: Certain words are not allowed in the service names. Unfortunately that list of prohibited words is not published anywhere. Please check the name you're giving and see if an offensive word can be formed using consecutive letters in the name (that's why I asked for the names you tried).

Comment: i tried "mynewdatabase", "team-indus-2014", "teamindusdatabasewp", "helpburntdatabase" and many more of same type.

Comment: I just tried all the names you provided above and did not encounter any issues (I did not went through the entire process to create the service). See this screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ArfQh.png. Can you share some screenshots?

Comment: i have tried the same, [see my screenshot](http://1drv.ms/QjFMAW) I don't know why it is showing the same thing.

Comment: Have you solved your problem ? Here is the same sittuation with me.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please give this another try? There was an issue with the service that has now been resolved.

Comment: That issue is apparently back, I'm getting the same response no matter what string of random 48 letters I type.

Answer (score 0):

This is new.

They deprecated the creation of Mobile Service at Manage Portal.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2016/05/20/azure-mobile-service-creation-fails-this-name-is-already-in-use/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/transition-of-azure-mobile-services/

End of line... now we have to get use to the horrible new portal! :s